# Mostrar valor arreglo asociativo

Tags: php, array

tengo un stored procedure que me devuelve el nombre de las provincias pasandole el id del país, id de provincia.
Obtengo un array luego de hacer un call.
print_r($a)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_loc] => 101 [descrip] => BA ) )
```

Quiero obtener el valor 'BA' para mostrar en un formulario,
hago un `echo $a[$localidad];` pero obtengo un vacío o 'Array'

P.D: `$localidad = '101';`

Que estoy haciendo mal? 
Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Hi, GAL! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: las prisas por cerrar no son buenas, me imagino que fue por estar en ingles, cuando con un simple mensaje se puede solucionar y de esta manera no ocupa espacio en la pila de revision, ademas del mal trago para el nuevo usuario pues no sabe el porque hasta que este totalmente cerrada. Simplemente es una observacion. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel aun que también opongo sobreuso de cierre hay que ver también que cerrar no significa borrar. El cierre de una pregunta en ingles por ejemplo evita que yo en mi volada respondo en ingles sin darme cuenta que estoy en SOes. Quizás cerrar y una corta explicación para que sirve el cierre y bajo que condiciones se reabre sería lo mejor.

Comment: Pido disculpas, es la costumbre de tipear en inglés. Un saludo

Comment: @Stefan Nolde Creo que tu punto de vista sobre que evita que respondas en ingles ... no se me habia ocurrido, y quizas el mensaje que deje no se aplique a tu caso pero en general suelen mandar a cerrar sin explicacion y sin mirar si es un nuevo usuario que en este caso lo es, y con un comentario... lo que dije arriba, no quiero crear tension por este tema solo era una observacion. Saludos

Comment: @Stefan Nolde P.D: se que cerrar no es borrar tu lo sabes y muchos tambien, pero cuando eres nuevo y te dice cerrada o algo asi pues impacta o ves que el contador de votos va en -1 -2 -3 o el de cerrar, creeme lo se por experiencia en SO. Y nadie explica nada. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel tension sobre este tema no puedes crear, ya existe por defecto, porque todo el mundo tiene su propia idea :). Y no te quería criticar, solamente llamar tu atención a otros consideraciones. El concepto de cierre para empezar nunca fue pensado como un "castigo", la idea es más dar el tiempo y al apoyo al usuario de crear una pregunta que merece y recibe la atención de los demás. Que mandar a cierre sin ofrecer una forma como se reabre no me gusta tampoco.

Comment: @Stefan Nolde Todo el mundo tiene sus propias ideas si, pero YO desde el comienzo intente que la gente se pusiera en el lugar de los nuevo hasta lo comente en el char largo y tendido sobre el que manda a cerrar deberia de tener la obligacion de comentar el porque, pero creo que no se podia implementar esa opcion o no procidia por x motivo, y ahora entro despues de algun tiempo y siguen igual, quizas es que nunca les ha pasado o  no se ponen el la piel de los nuevos. Bueno en fin. Saludos

Comment: Se necesita más de esta actitud en [el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) :) @AngelAngel

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que lo podes solucionar fácil con una función a la que le pasas el arreglo de localidades ($a) y el código de localidad (101) para que te devuelva la descripción, algo asi debería ser:

```
function nombrelocalidad($lista, $codigo)
{
    foreach ($lista as $localidad)
    {
        if ($localidad[id_loc] = $codigo)
        {
            return $localidad[descrip];
        }
    }
}
```

por ejemplo llamando la función con:

```
print_r(nombrelocalidad($a, 101));
```

te debería imprimir `BA`

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó! Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación: si deseas filtrar los registros, en donde el valor del campo "id_loc" sea igual a 101, este trabajo lo puede realizar el stored procedure, reduciendo la cantidad de procesos que debe realizar tu servidor de aplicación. En temas de rendimiento, esta alternativa es la correcta, ya que estas filtrando por ID de país, ID de provincia y podrías incluir el ID de localidad.

Si no tienes acceso a modificar el stored procedure, para obtener el valor que necesitas, debes recorrer el arreglo, comparando el valor del campo id_loc con el valor que buscas (101), como indica **M.Pacchiotti**

Comment: entiendo, el tema es que no tengo acceso a modificarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, un saludo